# kubernetes implement circuit braker pattern automatically?

Tags: spring, kubernetes, cloud, circuit

I am working on a spring cloud project. I implemented kubernetes and the question that arises is if kubernetes handle the circuit breaker pattern automatically?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't provide this natively. If you want a circuit breaker you need a service mesh like Istio for example.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#circuit-breakers